Function that returns a value in a HashMap using a parameter requires a lifetime for Struct<'a> but not for &str
To provide some background, I am writing a parser that creates objects that reference the text from some &'a str, where 'a ties all objects to the lifetime of that string. While parsing, I do some lookups to get previously-parsed items by name, which are stored in a HashMap that holds objects that are tied to the lifetime of the parsed string.
Previously, I was using a &str as the identifier, which worked. Here's a simplified example of what I had previously, which successfully compiled:
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct ReturnType<'a> {
    key: &'a str,
    value: &'a str
}

struct App<'a> {
    // Key type is &'a str
    map: HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>,
}

impl<'a> App<'a> {
    // Note that I don't have to specify the lifetime of `key` because it's only used for hashing;
    // the return type does not (and shouldn't) capture the lifetime of `key`, since it's returning
    // a value that comes from `self.map`
    pub fn lookup_value(&self, key: &str) -> Option<ReturnType<'a>> {
        self.map.get_key_value(key).map(|(k, v)| ReturnType { key: k.clone(), value: v })
    }
}

fn lookup<'a> (app: &'a App) -> Option<ReturnType<'a>> {
    // Note that I'm calling lookup_value referencing a value with a lifetime shorter than 'a
    let key = String::from("te");
    app.lookup_value(&key)
}

fn main() {
    let root = "testing";

    let app = App {
        map: HashMap::from([(&root[0..2], root)]),
    };

    lookup(&app);
}

However, I recently replaced &'a str in the HashMap key with a new wrapper type, StrRef<'a> which simply wraps around the same &'a str that was previously used. However, now it doesn't compile:
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Clone, Hash, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct StrRef<'a> {
    value: &'a str,
}

struct ReturnType<'a> {
    key: StrRef<'a>,
    value: &'a str
}

struct App<'a> {
    // Key type is StrRef<'a>
    map: HashMap<StrRef<'a>, &'a str>,
}

impl<'a> App<'a> {
    // I have tried `StrRef` and `StrRef<'b>` and all have the same error
    pub fn lookup_value(&self, key: &StrRef) -> Option<ReturnType<'a>> {
        // Error: explicit lifetime required in the type of `key`; lifetime `'a` required
        self.map.get_key_value(key).map(|(k, v)| ReturnType { key: k.clone(), value: v })
    }
}

fn lookup<'a> (app: &'a App) -> Option<ReturnType<'a>> {
    let key = String::from("te");
    app.lookup_value(&StrRef { value: &key })
}

fn main() {
    let root = "testing";

    let app = App {
        map: HashMap::from([(StrRef { value: &root[0..2] }, root)]),
    };

    lookup(&app);
}

I have tried providing key to the method as type StrRef and &StrRef but it doesn't compile, with the error shown in the code snippet above:
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `key`
  --> src/stack_overflow.rs:20:9
   |
19 |     pub fn lookup_value(&self, key: &StrRef) -> Option<ReturnType<'a>> {
   |                                     ------- help: add explicit lifetime `'a` to the type of `key`: `&stack_overflow::fails::StrRef<'a>`
20 |         self.map.get_key_value(key).map(|(k, v)| ReturnType { key: k.clone(), value: v })
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'a` required

The issue is that I am not able to assign the lifetime 'a to StrRef because I need to be able to provide a temporary StrRef to the lookup (where its inner &str composed from a format!()-ed string). I'm confused why the compiler seems to be capturing the lifetime of StrRef in the return type when it's only being used for hashing? I'm also confused why this works with a &str but not with StrRef.

Your StrRef wraps &str. And it implements Clone (btw it can implement Copy as well). So why are you passing it by ref? By doing this you have two lifetimes now. It's like passing str by double ref, i.e. &&str. That's the source of your problem.

I also tried providing it as StrRef without a reference but I still get the same error.

I've already tried those, and it didn't work. The only option I've tried that does work is marking it as StrRef<'a>, but as stated in my question, I can't impose that lifetime restriction.

T<'_> is identical to T, so that won't ever provide any help to the compiler.

The way to allow querying a map with different lifetime (or different type) is by implementing the Borrow trait. There is a little complication that arises from the fact that there exists a blanket implementation impl<T> Borrow<T> for T and it conflicts with naively implementing Borrow for different lifetimes, but that can be solved by introducing a wrapper type:
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Clone, Hash, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct StrRef<'a> {
    value: &'a str,
}

#[derive(Clone, Hash, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct StoredStrRef<'a>(StrRef<'a>);

impl<'a: 'b, 'b> std::borrow::Borrow<StrRef<'b>> for StoredStrRef<'a> {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &StrRef<'b> {
        &self.0
    }
}

struct ReturnType<'a> {
    key: StrRef<'a>,
    value: &'a str,
}

struct App<'a> {
    map: HashMap<StoredStrRef<'a>, &'a str>,
}

impl<'a> App<'a> {
    pub fn lookup_value(&self, key: &StrRef<'_>) -> Option<ReturnType<'a>> {
        self.map.get_key_value(key).map(|(k, v)| ReturnType {
            key: k.0.clone(),
            value: v,
        })
    }
}

fn lookup<'a>(app: &'a App) -> Option<ReturnType<'a>> {
    let key = String::from("te");
    app.lookup_value(&StrRef { value: &key })
}

fn main() {
    let root = "testing";

    let app = App {
        map: HashMap::from([(StoredStrRef(StrRef { value: &root[0..2] }), root)]),
    };

    lookup(&app);
}

Playground.

This solved my issue! I'm guessing there's no way to solve this without creating that wrapper struct? If there's no way around it, I'll mark this as the answer

@NicholasCrothers No, there is no way. With a bit of trickery it is possible to invert the struct - put it on the query instead of the map, though, if that's of any help.

I think the method you provided should be fine; a little awkward, but that's okay. It's all internal anyways. Are you able to explain why using &str works without needing any trickery? I'm still a bit confused by that.

@NicholasCrothers Because Borrow is implemented for str, not &str, and that type doesn't have a lifetime.

Right, that makes perfect sense. Thanks for all of your help!
